# hook_init() is executed more than once

Tags: debugging

When running xdebugger in `hook_init()`, I noticed that the debugger was stopping at same break points more than once.
Why is this so? Will it not affect the page load time?

Answer (score 1):

If I print some text within `hook_init()`, it is being printed only one time. This will not reduce the performance. Also `hook_init()` is called only once, from Drupal core.

Comment: Ok, but that s not my Question why in Xdebug init is called more than once ?

Comment: You should be able to see the backtrace how it's called, post that in your question. As @sathishkumar mentioned, Drupal core does not call that hook twice.